# How can I convert all .svg files in a directory to .pdf on Linux in the commandline

Tags: pdf, batch, svg

When I have a directory full of .svg files, e.g. from Inkscape, how is it possible to convert them to .pdf files?

Similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/381125/how-do-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-pdf-on-linux) approach for a single file, but as a batch command for a whole directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an SVG to a PDF on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/381125/how-do-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-pdf-on-linux)

Answer (score 21):

In [this](https://superuser.com/questions/381125/how-do-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-pdf-on-linux?newreg=353d8eb092b74d1f93d69eb75fe14eae) post, the procedure is shown for a single file.

The relevant command is:

```
rsvg-convert -f pdf -o t.pdf t.svg
```

For a whole directory, a simple bash script does the job:

```bash
for i in *.svg;do rsvg-convert -f pdf -o ${i%.*}.pdf $i;done
```

This assumes that you have rsvg-convert installed, if not you can get it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

Comment: How do you convert the whole directory's svg files into a single pdf file ?

Comment: The simple approach is to merge all the generated pdfs.
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/886934/merge-all-pdf-files-from-one-folder
Command:  
pdftk *.pdf output mergedfiles.pdf