# Is there a way to convert SVG to EPS on Linux and retain gradients and transparency?

Tags: linux, conversion, inkscape, svg, eps

I'm using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) to do graphic design on Linux and I'm quite happy with it and *SVG* files. Unfortunately, a client requests an * EPS* file. The designed logo contains gradients and the client also asked for transparent background.

Inkscape has an export option for *eps* files, but [according to this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/75919) the file cannot contain gradients nor transparency, otherwise the output file will be rasterized.

Since this post and similar posts are about 5 years old or older, I was wondering if there is a way to get non-rasterized *eps* files (with gradients and transparency) nowadays.

Comment: Try `inkscape -E out.eps in.svg`. It should normally do the conversion at full quality.

Comment: I tried that, but I get `Unknown option -E` (Inkscape 1.0.1 on Linux Manjaro)

Comment: Check your `man Inkscape`. According to [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inkscape) this is `-E FILENAME , --export-eps= FILENAME `, but maybe yours is called differently.

Comment: I think that is outdated, according to the [man page](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man100.html) on inkscape.org, there is no `-E` anymore. It seems the replacement is `--export-type=TYPE[,TYPE]*`. That works, but delivers the same result as the GUI version (rasterized eps file)

Comment: Does `--export-type=eps` work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit *Enter*. That was the second part of my comment (I edited it then)

Comment: This is a problem with `inkscape`, but there are solutions. See [this solution](http://blog.linuxgrrl.com/2013/08/12/how-to-produce-vector-eps-with-cmyk-color-using-free-software/) for example.

Comment: Your link is the same as the one mentioned in the post I referenced in the question, it only works if you remove transparency, masks, gradients etc. in the inkscape file

Comment: OK, so here are some more that claimed success: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245685/inkscape-screws-up-eps-files) and [link2](https://superuser.com/questions/381125/how-do-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-pdf-on-linux). An online convertor that might work is [convertio](https://convertio.co/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in a command prompt:

```
inkscape -o eps-filename.eps orig-file.svg
```

Here `-o` is used for export. This works on my inkspace version 1.1.2.

Comment: Does this address the core issue of the question? “Inkscape has an export option for eps files, but according to this post the file cannot contain gradients nor transparency, otherwise the output file will be rasterized.”

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).